# SQL Join Query Assistance on mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my basic query

```
 SELECT * from ACTIONS where STARTDATE < '2015-05-01'   and EXPORTDATE is null
```

I need to join that with table Contracts and further only include the records where SERIAL is the same in both tables and ENDDATE (in Contracts) < '2015-03-01'

Once I review the data, I need to do an update query on ACTIONS setting STARTDATE to a new date for the same records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The join for the select statement:

```
SELECT * from ACTIONS 
JOIN Contracts ON Actions.Serial = Contracts.Serial
WHERE Actions.STARTDATE < '2015-05-01' 
  AND Actions.EXPORTDATE is null
  AND Contracts.EndDate < '2015-03-01'
```

The update (using the MySQL update with join syntax):

```
UPDATE Actions
JOIN Contracts ON Actions.Serial = Contracts.Serial
SET Actions.StartDate = 'NewDate'
WHERE Actions.STARTDATE < '2015-05-01' 
  AND Actions.EXPORTDATE is null
  AND Contracts.EndDate < '2015-03-01'
```

If you want to shorten the queries you can use aliases for the tables like `Contracts AS C` and then refer to the table using the alias like this: `C.EndDate < '2015-03-01'`.

Comment: Thank you the select is working, but the update is giving me a 1064 error saying there is a syntax is bad for the "WHERE ..... is null and Contracts.'

Comment: @mloraditch Oh my bad sorry, the `where` clause should come after the `set` statement I think.

Comment: Doh, I should have caught that too! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Or using an alternative notation.

```
SELECT * from ACTIONS act
INNER JOIN CONTRACTS con on act.serial = con.serial 
where con STARTDATE < '2015-05-01'   
and act.EXPORTDATE is null
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional info!